# Django project crashes server when admin backend is accessed

Tags: django, apache, wsgi, web-frameworks, django-wsgi

### Problem

I am running apache2 on my local ubuntu server. I set up a Django project using `django-admin startproject site` and set up my virtual host to use a WSGI Daemon process to run the Django project. This worked and the site is accessible through its IP `192.168.1.3`.

When I go to /admin, it allows me to log in and see the initial backend but loads for 5 minutes then goes to a 500 error when I click anything or reload, even when trying to access the non-admin index page. This persists until I run `systemctl restart apache2` and completely restart apache or wait ~10-15 minutes until it fixes itself (only to break again immediately if I access /admin pages).

### Versions

Django version 4.1.5

mod-wsgi version 4.9.4

### My Attempts

If I run the project with `python manage.py runserver`, I can access it on `192.168.1.3:8000` and fully use the /admin backend, even creating new users, etc. I then thought it was the WSGI Daemon process somehow messing it up, so I followed the linked section of this page: https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi#using-mod-wsgi-express-with-django and ran the site with `python manage.py runmodwsgi`. The site completely works on `192.168.1.3:8000` along with the /admin, and I can create new users etc., which points to it having nothing to do with the WSGI setup (as well as the non-admin pages working fine on the virtual host WSGI).

I have fully deleted and restarted the Django project, as well as setting up new virtual host .conf files with the proper WSGI information, etc.

I read about an /admin loading issue back in Django 3.0, but I am on 4.1 so that is unrelated.

**I am at a complete loss at what the issue could be at this point. Why won't my /admin section work on the virtual host??**

EDIT:

The issue is actually definitely the WSGI somehow. I am getting this is my apache error log:

```
[Sun Jan 29 09:27:12.388714 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 67623:tid 140212873184832] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 192.168.1.10:63055] mod_wsgi (pid=67623): Failed to proxy response from daemon., referer: http://192.168.1.3/admin/
[Sun Jan 29 09:27:14.427470 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 67624:tid 140211782657600] [client 192.168.1.10:63053] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'Portfolio': /var/www/Portfolio/Portfolio/wsgi.py, referer: http://192.168.1.3/admin/auth/
[Sun Jan 29 09:27:14.949762 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 67624:tid 140211279357504] [client 192.168.1.10:63056] Timeout when reading response headers from daemon process 'Portfolio': /var/www/Portfolio/Portfolio/wsgi.py, referer: http://192.168.1.3/admin/auth/
[Sun Jan 29 09:27:16.385674 2023] [wsgi:error] [pid 67623:tid 140212856399424] [client 192.168.1.10:63100] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'Portfolio': /var/www/Portfolio/Portfolio/wsgi.py
```

I still do not know what the solution is, though.

Answer (score 1):

https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/django-apache-deployment-not-working-as-intended/15800

I found the solution. Somehow during the whole setup, adding `WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}` to the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file was never recommended, at least not that I noticed, but it worked and all the admin functionality works on the virtual host through WSGI Daemon.

Hope this can help someone else.